# About two mutually related, future actions

Tags: phrases, verbs, future, when

Is it correct to say: "I will do that thing when I will talk to him."?

Comment: Can you be more precise which part of the sentence seems problematic to you?

Comment: @RegDwightBBB: I mean "..if I will talk to him...". But even "after I..."

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot parse that.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВB: ?

Comment: @RegDwightΒВB: Sorry mod, could I ask you why my question is unsuitable?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ungrammatical. In such cases, English expresses the future with the present tense: *I will do that thing when I talk to him.* It is also unlikely that a native speaker would say *I will do that thing.* It would normally be *I’ll do that*.

Comment: Thank you! Of course, `I'll do that` sounds more colloquial,as well.

Comment: Excuse me, Barry England, is my question inappropriate?

Comment: It's not really for me to say.

Comment: @A_nto2: I'm not a moderator.