# Saying about many related events in the future

Tags: modal-verbs, future, conditionals, subjunctive-mood

My question relates to these questions :

- [Conditionals in the future](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45811/conditionals-in-the-future)
- [Future tense in conditional clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/future-tense-in-conditional-clauses)
- [“If I go..” vs. “If I will go..” referring to the future](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61299/if-i-go-vs-if-i-will-go-referring-to-the-future?rq=1)
- [About two mutually related, future actions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73707/about-two-mutually-related-future-actions)

What is the common way in English (and American English) to say about many related events that can happen due to some condition:

> I suppose if this gadget [will be] packed in cardboard box there [will be] less chances that the package [will be] stopped at customs for any additional inspection of its contents.

or even:

> I suppose if this gadget [will be] packed in cardboard box there [will be] less chances that the package [will be] stopped at customs for any additional inspection so there [will be] no delay in delivery.

Note: I used "[will be]" to depict that action will occur in a future - I understand that it is incorrect.

Comment: In your particular example, you would use *is* packed, but then all the others can be *will be* - that is a correct usage.

Comment: The verb(s) **in** the 'if' clause should be in the present tense, but the others can be in the future.

Comment: I agree with @Rory.  But (1) we would usually say “packed in **a** cardboard box” (or “… if these gadgets are packed in cardboard boxes”), and (2) I believe that “less chance” is more common than “less chances”.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentences are conditional and the preferred verb form is the subjunctive:

> I suppose if this gadget *were* packed in a cardboard box, there *would be* less chance that the package *would be* stopped at customs for any additional inspection, so there *would be* no delay in delivery.

If you want to emphasize the future possibility of such packing, you could say

> I suppose if this gadget *were to be* packed in a cardboard box, there *would be* less chance that the package *would be* stopped at customs for any additional inspection, so there *would be* no delay in delivery.

If you want to reduce the repetion of the verb form, you could switch to gerunds:

> I suppose if this gadget *were to be* packed in a cardboard box, there *would be* less chance of the package *being* stopped at customs for any additional inspection, thus *avoiding* delay in delivery.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't use *will* in the *if* conditional clause, because that would mean that you're talking about a case where ***the gadget*** was willing to be packed in a cardboard box (as explained in [my response](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61308/15299) to the third question above), and that's clearly not what you want to say.

If you just use the present tense -- *is packed* -- in the *if* clause, then you mean that:

- *provided that the gadget gets packed in a cardboard box, certain results are likely.*

and that seems right.

Likelihood, however, is a modal notion ([modals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) refer to possibility, probability, and necessity), so a [modal auxiliary](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) like *will* seems appropriate for the conclusion clauses. Or *might*, or *could*, or any other modal that makes sense; *will* is **not** "the future tense"; it's just another modal auxiliary verb.

BTW, *chance* is a mass noun, and therefore singular, in the clause

- *there will be less chance that **`S`***.

Comment: Somewhere down the line, *will* has gained widely accepted usage, proscriptively even, as a modal aux.  Where there's a will, there's a way?

Answer (score 0):

The examples you provided are in correct English, you can use these sentences if you want to. It isn't all too common but it is correct English nonetheless.

All the instances of will be in this sentence have different meanings. You can only leave it out if it maintains the meaning, or keeps referring to the same part of the sentence (in this case it doesn't). Take for example your first sentence: the first will be refers to the packing, the second refers to less chance and the last one refers to being stopped at customs. Thus, you cannot word it differently.

Also, the first will be is correct if you let it be packed by someone else and you are asking whether or not you should let it be packed in another way.